# How to capture Textbox data using PowerShell and Windows Forms?

Tags: forms, powershell, textbox

I am trying to create a windows form using PowerShell and then manipulate the data entered. The problem I am having is that I can get the code to work if I copy/paste it into a PowerShell window however I cannot get it to work if I save the exact same code to a PS1 file. I don't understand that.

If you try out the example in this article: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx it will work fine when you paste it into an open command prompt. If you try to save this code as a PS1 and run the PS1 in the PowerShell window I get nothing back when click OK on the dialog.

Can someone help me understand why it doesn't work as a PS1 file?

Comment: That's interesting.  I tried it but my experience was a little different.  The behavior was the same, either way.  In both cases, it seems that `$x` was not assigned the string entered in the field.  However, if I echo `$objTextBox.Text` then it does contain the text that I entered.  For some reason, this assignment `$x=$objTextBox.Text` does not seem to be working (scoping problem?).  However, for me, it was the same, regardless of whether I used the console for a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable assignment statement (`$x=$objTextBox.Text`) sets value within default scope, which is `Local` by default. 
As assignment statement is within `{...}` the variable value is not visible out of the assignment scope.

You can change the assignment statement `$x=$objTextBox.Text` with the:

```
$global:x=$objTextBox.Text
```

More info:

- [Set-Variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347562.aspx)
- [about_Scopes](http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd315289.aspx)

Comment: Using the example in *the script referenced by the OP*, I'm just wondering, how can you retrieve the user-entered data after submission, if there were multiple inputs (dynamically created using a loop)?

Answer (score 1):

As Matej stated this is a scope issue, and he provided an excellent solution to being able to manipulate variables from within a child scope.

I wanted to provide an alternative way to work around this issue. That is to declare variables at the beginning of the script with `New-Variable` and use the `-Option AllScope` argument. For example I will use the [script that was referenced in the OP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx). Insert a line at line 3 to read:

```
New-Variable -Name x -Option AllScope
```

Now when you run the script it will output whatever you typed into the box because the variable `$x` is consistent across all scopes.

Comment: Thanks - this works as well as Metej's info. I like this idea a little better because I can assign all my variable ahead of time for use later on.

Comment: Using the example in *the script referenced by the OP*, I'm just wondering, how can you retrieve the user-entered data after submission, if there were multiple inputs (dynamically created using a loop)?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo That's a completely different question. You should create a new thread for that. It would involve storing and retrieving data, where this was a matter of scope.